# Please see the Algebra question given in the image below-

Tags: linear-algebra

[Click here to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2vk9.jpg)

If there was any condition given on p,q,r,s like they are odd/even or they  are consecutive integers, I could have done that easily but with only the condition that p,q,r,s are distinct, I have no idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Please do *not* post links to pictures of questions. It doesn't take much effort to transcribe the question here with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I also am unsure how to attack the problem.  My guess, which could easily be wrong is that the problem seems to require a knowledge of Field Theory.  There are two possibilities: [1] You made this problem up, or saw it somewhere on the Internet, perhaps as part of a contest. [2] This problem is from a book or class that you are involved in.  ...see next comment

Comment: Under option [1], I suggest abandoning the problem temporarily, and instead (if you are interested) studying Field Theory, so that you can gracefully acquire the **tools** (AKA knowledge of theorems, knowledge of worked examples, knowledge of attacked exercises, stretched intuition) necessary to elegantly attack the problem. ...see next comment

Comment: Under option [2], assuming that the problem composer is not deranged, the given exercise must be an application of the **tools** that the book/class has provided to you.  What are these tools?  In this context, consider that your posting has a number of defects with respect to the MathSE protocol.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer of Rkb, which uses an approach that did not occur to me, actually *supports* the point that I am making in my comments.  I suspect that if I had studied a Field Theory book, that the book would have included similar theorems, worked examples, and assigned exercises.  So, my intuition would have been stretched, and I would have become moderately fluent with the pertinent tools.  So, I would have had a *chance* to elegantly attack the problem.

Comment: @user2661923 As you can see below, the solution to the problem has been posted by a guy without the use of Field Theory. And it's a question from a book suggested by our teacher, so No, I haven't made up this problem and neither have I randomly posted it from the Internet.

Comment: To Maths noob: Did the posted answer involve concepts that  you were exposed to in either your class, or the suggested book?  What was the intent of the problem composer?  You never specified the source of the problem (AKA the name of your class and the title of the book).  Also, you did not specify the pertinent tools that either your teacher or the book's author intended that you use.  Where ever the *tools* originated (i.e. Field Theory or somewhere else), either you had previous exposure to these tools or you did not have previous exposure to these tools.  My previous comments stand.

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry am quite new to StackExchange and this was my first ever question here. And Yes, we were exposed to these concepts, I don't know the problem source. Our teacher gave us an assignment without mentioning the source, so I don't know. I am currently in High School. This assignment was given for Algebra practice and needs Middle+High School concepts only.
And let's end this convo here and rather focus on the question rather than its source. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question:Let $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n$, where all the coefficients are integers. Suppose there are four distinct integers $p,q,r$
and $s$ such that $f(p)=f(q)=f(r)=f(s)=5$. Show that there is no integer $k$ such that $f(k)=8$.

---

Let $g(x)=f(x)-5$, then we have $g(p)=g(q)=g(r)=g(s)=0$
$\implies g(x)=h(x)(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)$ for some polynomial $h(x)$,with integrer coefficients.

Say, there is some $k $ such that $f(k)=8\implies g(k)=3\implies h(k)(k-p)(k-q)(k-r)(k-s)=3$.

Now, $p,q,r,s$ are all distinct,hence atleast $2$ of the $4$ factors $(k-p),(k-q),(k-r),(k-s)$,must be integers other than $0,1,-1$ , but then this contradicts that $3$ is a prime.